# Fastest way to find out whether row or one of set of rows exists in database accesed via SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

Django has `queryset.exists()` method that fetch bool indicating whether or not at least 1 row with specific conditions exists.

for example

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], usernmae='test').exists()
```

It would just return bool `True` in case at least one row with these conditions exists and False other way around.

**Question** - is it something like that could be done in SQLAlchemy > 2.0 with **asyncpg** driver?
Best I have found is `await session.get` but it potentially could fetch multiple objectds from DB, dezerialize them, etc, whereas I only need to find out if at least one of these rows does exists?

Comment: It seems you miss a minimal working example here. Please check your code there might be a typo in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
async with async_session() as session:
    stmt = select(User.id).where(User.id.in_([4, 5])).limit(1)
    result = await session.scalars(stmt)
    item = result.first()
```

`item` will be an `int` (truthy) if at least one row exists, otherwise it will be `None` (falsy). If you want a true boolean value you could always do

```py
    row_exists = bool(result.first())
```

instead.

A more complete example of ORM with async can be found in the SQLAlchemy documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/_modules/examples/asyncio/async_orm.html).

Comment: Couldn't the OP use [exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) or is that not so fast?

Comment: IIRC, `exists()` is primarily used to render `EXISTS (subquery)` as in `SELECT … WHERE EXISTS (SELECT … )` which might not hinder performance too much (given how clever PostgreSQL is) but would be a bit convoluted.

Comment: @Gord Thompson 
Thanks. This is what i have been looking for.